# Simple Button Not Working

Tags: android, android-studio

I am just trying to make a simple recording app. But my stop button doesn't seem to work. It doesn't show any error, but it isn't working.
I couldn't find any errors.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
Button start, stop;
public MediaRecorder recorder = null;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start_button);
    stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop_button);

    start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

                                 @Override
                                 public void onClick(View v) {

                                     switch (v.getId()) {
                                         case R.id.start_button:
                                             startRecord();break;
                                          case R.id.stop_button:
                                              stopRecord();  break;
                                     }
                                 }

                             }
    );

}

public void startRecord() {
    recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    recorder.reset();
    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    recorder.setOutputFile(getFilePath());

    try {
        recorder.prepare();
        recorder.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


public void stopRecord() {
  if(recorder!=null) {
      System.out.println("Stop Pressed");

      recorder.stop();

      recorder.reset();
      recorder.release();
      recorder = null;
  }

}


private String getFilePath() {    

    String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
    File file = new File(filepath, "Audio Capture");

    if (!file.exists())
        file.mkdirs();

    filepath=file.getAbsolutePath()+"/Record.mp4";
    System.out.println(filepath);
    return (filepath);
}



}
```

Waiting for an answer. Thanks in Advance;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must set 'OnClickListener' for 'Stop' button, too.

I think this modification is better:

```
start.setOnClickListener(btnListener);
stop.setOnClickListener(btnListener);

View.OnClickListener btnListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.start_button:
                startRecord();break;
            case R.id.stop_button:
                stopRecord();  break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This modifications works. Just another doubt, When i open the recorded file, it says 'can't play this link'. What should i do?
But when i move the file to some-other place, then is plays.

Comment: @Gokul Krishna Did you close the file stream after you stop recording?

Comment: I don't understand file stream. I stopped the recording and had the app open. I went to the file and tried opening it. Even when the app is closed it does not open. It opens only when i move the file.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you a hint. In order to listen to an Button click, you need to have a listener registered with that view.

Comment: Yeah..!! Got it..simple mistake :(

Comment: I have another doubt. When i open the recorded file, it says 'can't play this link'. What should i do? But when i move the file to some-other place, then is plays.